# Unable to install php mongo extension in centos 6.5 and php 5.4

Tags: php, linux, mongodb, centos6.5

I have installed PHP 5.4 and mongodb in Centos 6.5.

I tried to install the PHP mongodb extension using the instruction given in http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-the-mongodb-php-driver-extension-on-centos-6/, but when I run `php -m | grep -i mongo`, it shows the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mongo: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

---

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: The issue appears to be that you've got a `mongo` module compiled against the wrong version of the PHP module API

Answer (score 1):

I'd manually install it. This is exactly the same thing which pecl/pear does:

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/mongo-1.6.5.tgz
tar xzf mongo-1.6.5.tgz
cd mongo-1*
phpize
./configure --enable-mongo --with-php-config=php-config --prefix=/usr/lib/php5/
make && make install
```

The correct version configuration gets initialized by the `phpize` command.

Make sure your lib path is `/usr/lib/php5`, if not, change it in the `./configure` parameter.